# How To: transform DocumentImpl into XmlDocument

Tags: java, java1.4

I am migrating an application from java 1.4 to 1.7,

One of the runtime errors i have is a class cast exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DocumentImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.crimson.tree.XmlDocument
```

Code:

```
doc = getDocBuilder().parse(inputSource); // returning DeferredDocumentImpl
((XmlDocument) doc).changeNodeOwner(rootElement); // casting Exception here
```

is there any workaround to transform around these two types ?

Comment: It looks like you are doing an explicit cast somewhere - Java 7 does not have Apache Crimson bundled. You should probably remove all the Apache Crimson code and replace it with the JAXP API.

Comment: Its a really large set of projects so I didn't really want to change all code that's using crimson (wich is alot) :(

Comment: Crimson is no longer bundled with the JRE, but if you download it yourself and add it to your application's classpath (or add a dependency if you're using a dependency manager) then it should still work.

Comment: @IanRoberts I think one would need to set it as the default JAXP provider also, would would be putting it in the endorsed location of the JVM.

Comment: @BoristheSpider only if you have other JAXP providers on the project's classpath as well.  Crimson provides a `META-INF/services` file so should be picked up automatically if it's the only available provider (apart from the internal one in rt.jar)